# Springfox swagger-ui endpoint duplicate when using tag

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

In my spring-boot project with springfox swagger 2.9.2, I have controller annotated with RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/api/v1/auth")
public class AuthenticationResource {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Authenticate user", tags = {"Authentication"})
    @PostMapping("login")
    public void login(@RequestBody @Valid LoginDto loginDto) {
        ...
    }
}
```

After I've added tags to ApiOperation, I got duplicated endpoint in swagger-ui.
I have empty authentication-resource without any endpoints and Authentication resource with login endpoint.

[image]

[image]

This didn't happen in older swagger versions.
How can I remove empty api from swagger-ui?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2406#issuecomment-397740857) post on GitHub adding `@Api(tags = { "Authentication" })` to the Controller would solve your problem. I tried it, it works.